# PayPal classic API express checkout - tax issue

Tags: api, paypal

I am trying to create a payment using Express Checkout. it works fine if I don't include the TaxTotal. As soon as I do I get an error "Tax total is invalid".

```
        var itemTotal = new BasicAmountType(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CurrencyCodeType)).Cast<CurrencyCodeType>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.ToString() == cart.Item.Currency.ToString()), cart.NetTotal.ToString());
        var orderTotal = new BasicAmountType(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CurrencyCodeType)).Cast<CurrencyCodeType>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.ToString() == cart.Item.Currency.ToString()), cart.GrossTotal.ToString());
        var taxTotal = new BasicAmountType(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CurrencyCodeType)).Cast<CurrencyCodeType>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.ToString() == cart.Item.Currency.ToString()), cart.TaxTotal.ToString());

        paymentDetails.ItemTotal = itemTotal;
        paymentDetails.OrderTotal = orderTotal;
        paymentDetails.TaxTotal = taxTotal;
```

If I remove the ItemTotal and TaxTotal the payment processes fine, but I need to show the tax breakdown.

FYI, the amounts are, ItemTotal = 175, OrderTotal = 210, TaxTotal = 35.

Can anyone confirm what the problem is or what is missing from my code?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, it was similar to the solution suggested by Andrew.

I was using a decimal for the order total which was 210.000. I rounded this to 210.00 to knock a decimal off and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the decimals so it becomes 175.00.  I would do that for all amount fields when using PayPal's API's.

If that doesn't work, post a copy of the actual request that you're sending so we can verify what is actually getting sent.